# Synchronize pyserial with Arduino

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I want to use Serial communication with Arduino in Python in order to make a motor move according to a specified color. I have a problem with `pyserial` synchronisation with Arduino.

Here is my Python code:

```
import serial

# Serial object for communication with Arduino
ser = serial.Serial(port='COM8', baudrate=9600, timeout=.1)
# write distance and radius to Arduino through Serial Communication
ser.write(str(length))
ser.write(bytes('#', "UTF-8"))
ser.write(bytes(radius))
ser.write(bytes('/', "UTF-8"))
```

and here's my Arduino code:

```
void loop() {
  while(Serial.available())
  {
    inChar = Serial.read();
    if(inChar == '#'){
      while(Serial.available()){
        inChar = Serial.read();
        if(inChar == '/'){
          break;
        }
        inputStringR += inChar;
      }break;
    }
    inputStringL += inChar;  
  }
```

and here's my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\project gdevelop\belajar web1\clor.py", line 69, in <module>
    ser.write(str(length))
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 310, in write
    data = to_bytes(data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 65, in to_bytes
    raise TypeError('unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: {!r}'.format(seq))
TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: '267'
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: `ser.write(f"{length}#{radius}/".encode())`

Comment: And `bytes(radius)` won't do what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the String that you're trying to sent trough serial.
Acording to [Serial.py documentation](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html) serial.write sent bytes data trough the port.

Using encode would transform the String data to bytes.

```
import serial
length = 5
radius = 2
encode_data= ""
# Serial object for communication with Arduino
ser = serial.Serial(port='COM8', baudrate=9600, timeout=.1)
# write distance and radius to Arduino through Serial Communication
ser.write(str(length).encode())
encode_data = "#"
ser.write(encode_data.encode())
ser.write(str(radius).encode())
 encode_data = "/"
ser.write(encode_data.encode())
```

Comment: Why `encode_data`? Why not just  `ser.write(b"#")`?

Comment: Both do the same thing but using the encode function would give more flexibility and control, in case of using special characterers that are not part of ASCII set, you could specify other type of encoding and made sure a correct data convertion.